# Add String in Json Object

Tags: json, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to create rapidjson object. When I insert string type variable , it give me 'true' instead of original value of string object.I'm doing like that

```
rapidjson::Document::AllocatorType& allocator = document.GetAllocator();
rapidjson::Value object(rapidjson::kObjectType);
object.AddMember("string", &playerId , allocator);
```

but if I insert string value directly , it give fine result. This is working right :

```
object.AddMember("string", "stringValue" , allocator);
```

Comment: What is the type of playerID?

Comment: playerId type should be in const char*